# How can I extract only an inode number for a file in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

just a quick question. I want to use my inode number in my bash script however, I need some help.

I'm using command `ls -i "filename"`, which echoes "inode number" "filename". The problem is, I only need inode number. Is there a way, where i can "slice" the output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `stat` command with `%i` to get only inode nuymbers:

```
stat -c '%i' *
```

Most of the utilities/commands use to get inode use `lstat` system call which is the one used by `stat` command too.

Comment: GNU stat uses `-c`. BSD stat appears to use `-f`.

Answer (score 2):

you can also awk over the ls

```
    -bash-3.2$ ls -i current.py | awk '{print $1}'
```